# delete specific character "[" from a file

Tags: sed, special-characters

I want to remove a character "[" from a file.  I tried

```
 sed -i 's/[//g' 'filename'
```

however I get the following error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `[` character is special as it starts a `[...]` group (a bracketed expression).

With `sed` on OpenBSD, your command gives a more helpful error message:

```
$ sed 's/[//g'
sed: 1: "s/[//g": unbalanced brackets ([])
```

To delete all `[` characters using `sed`, escape it:

```
sed -i 's/\[//g' file
```

Or put it inside a bracketed expression:

```
sed -i 's/[[]//g' file
```

Or, use `tr`,

```
tr -d '[' <file >file.new
```

Also, don't use in-place editing with `sed` until you know the expression that you are trying out actually works, or you will possibly have to restore your data from backups.

Comment: I second Kusalananda's observation: The first step while using sed should be to use it with the -e flag like `sed -e ...` so that one is sure what would happen if the changes were to be made permanent beyond rollback. For example, in your example, you would type `sed -e 's/\[//g' 'filename'` which would do a dry run and tell you what exactly gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was originally tagged with `awk` and for no real good reason:

```
awk '{gsub(/\[/, "")}1' file >newfile
```

This will print the file with all `[` removed and save it to `newfile`.

Using `gawk` you can make edits in place:

```
gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/\[/, "")}1' file
```

I wouldn't use either of these though unless you are also using `awk` to take other actions on the file.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the tag since it appeared to have no bearing on the question whatsoever.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I know, but it's not the _worst_ way to do it.

Comment: This works, but depending on the OS, `awk` is a symlink to `gawk` and it has to be version 4.1 or later for `-i inplace`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that depending on the OS, they are the same thing so it doesn't matter which one is used and that if it's not at least version 41., the `-i inplace` switch isn't going to work. I'm only suggesting that you add the second thing in particular to your answer so that someone with an earlier version doesn't try to use `-i inplace` and find that it doesn't work.

Comment: The fact that `awk` may be `gawk` is sort of moot.  Also while the version information is correct I just don't see it that necessary to ensure someone is using <6 year old software on a secondary answer.  Non-portable methods are non-portable, if they don't work for you use the portable method.